# using k-means with a placeholder as an input

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm running `KMeans` to cluster the data like

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=N, random_state=0).fit(X)
Centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

Now, I need to use `placeholder` and use the code like the following

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, num_features))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=N, random_state=0).fit(X)
Centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

However, it dose not work. Is there any equivalent way in tensorflow (`tensorflow.compat.v1`) that I can use both `KMeans` and `placeholder`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "*it does not work*"? Please post the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from confusion about what a placeholder is.

Roughly speaking, these are tf objects thought to be there as a promise to get a variable.
Your `X` has a shape, but it is an *empty* object. In order to fit a model you have to give it something containing data, and this is not the case. If you really want to use a tensorflow object (and I advise against it) you have to put data into it, for example using `tf.variable`.